# I have an image dataset how can I split it according to train.csv and test.csv

Tags: object, object-detection

I have two .csv files one train.csv with image names in .png format and similarly test.csv with image names in .png format. I have one big image dataset of 14000 images how can I split it accordingly to .csv file so that I can detect boundaries around objects

Comment: Your question is not very clear. in your .csv do you have the name of the file and the bounding boxes?

Comment: Actually there is train.csv with x_min,x_max and y_min,y_max and I have to train my image dataset on basis of it and then in test.csv I have to fill the x_min,x_max and y_min,y_max from my predictions.Can you please tell me how can I approach

Comment: Ok, let's do a brief recap. You need to have the bounding boxes coordinates for both train.csv and test.csv. Then, transform them to TFRecords, and use them for train and eval your model. You need the bboxes of the test data too.

Comment: I have coordinates of bounding boxes for some images provided in train.csv and we have to train our model on that and fill the empty coordinate boxes of test.csv

Comment: So, you're entire dataset is only train.csv, that isn't properly a train set. You need to split this train.csv in two file, the real train.csv and the real test.csv. Both of these files need to have the list of images, bounding boxes, and class. Your actual test.csv is, actually, only a set of unseen data, useless at this very moment: you may want to use it after you create a model, and want to test it on unseen data. Hint: I advise you to study the approach well before dive into training a model, Internet is full of walktrough (dependings on OS and your tensorflow release)